# How to deny access to invalid $_GET parameters

Tags: security

For example, there is a pager with 10 pages. How to deny access if $_GET['page'] is bigger than 9 or is not numeric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no 'catch-all' method for this sort of thing, but on an individual basis you would probably want to perform a manual check in [`hook_init()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) in a custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_init() {
  if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    if (!is_numeric($_GET['page']) || $_GET['page'] > 9) {
      drupal_access_denied();
    }
  }
}
```

I imagine you'll need to add further conditions to the above code to make it more contextual to your specific situation.

**EDIT**

As MPD mentions it might be better to use `drupal_not_found()` in place of `drupal_access_denied()`...it's a better semantic representation of what you're actually doing.

Comment: Personally, I would drupal_not_found() the request.

Comment: @MPD Yeah that would be better actually, it would represent the reason for the error better than an access denied